# Trouble computing recursive value of this function

Tags: function, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

```
let rec f (l: int list) : int * int = 
    begin match l with
    | [] -> (0,0)
    | [x] (x,x)
    | x::y::tl -> let (a,b) = f tl in 
                  (x + a, y + b)
    end

let r = f [2;3;4;5;6]
```

I'm thinking that the answer would compute to `r = (6,6)` because if you keep calling the recursive function on the tail, you'll end up with the last item in the list, thus it will match to the second case but I have no idea if this is correct or why this is the case. Really, I don't understand the use of `let (a,b) = f tl in (x + a, y + b)`.

Comment: I would suggest running it to find out what `r` *actually* is, then work back from there.

Comment: Doesn't really help...the problem is I don't really understand what the last part of the syntax is translating to.

Comment: Figured out the pattern, but the syntax still seems a bit fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain `let (a, b) = f tl in (x + a, y + b)`. Maybe that will help.

The pattern for this case is `x :: y :: tl`. So this means that `tl` represents the tail of the tail of the list. I.e. it represents the list after you remove the two elements at the front.

Along these same lines, `x` represents the first element of the list and `y` represents the second element.

The recursive call to `f` is going to return whatever `f` returns for `tl`, which is what you're trying to figure out. This will be a pair of numbers, as you can tell from the pattern `(a, b)`.

The result of the whole expression (which is the result of `f` except when the list is very short) is `(x + a, y + b)`. In other words, it adds the first element of the list to the first number of the pair and the second element of the list to the second element of the pair.

Comment: Ah okay. So it recursively calls `f tl` until we get the tuple `(a,b)`, then uses that to evaluate `(x + a, y + b)`? So would it actually return `(10, 11)` as the tuple output?

Answer (score 0):

```
# f [2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : int * int = (12, 14)
```

How did we get here?

Correcting and simplifying your function (by removing extraneous `begin...end`:

```
let rec f l = 
  match l with
  | [] -> (0, 0)
  | [x] -> (x, x)
  | x::y::tl -> 
    let (a, b) = f tl in 
    (x + a, y + b)
```

When we call `f [2; 3; 4; 5; 6]` we can trace the recursive calls.

```
f [2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
  x = 2
  y = 3
  a, b = f [4; 5; 6]
    x = 4 
    y = 5
    a, b = f [6] -> (6, 6)
    result: (4 + 6, 5 + 6) -> (10, 11)
  a = 10
  b = 11
  result: (2 + 10, 3 + 11) -> (12, 14)
```

Now, a function written this way is inherently non-tail-recursive. We have to iterate all the way to the end of the list before we can unwind the call stack to generate a result. This will generate a stack overflow for very large lists (though large enough lists to create that issue may also generate integer overflow issues). The key to cracking this is to realize what the function is actually doing. As it turns out, it's summing up integers at "even" and "odd" positions in a list.

We can use `List.fold_left` which is tail-recursive if we set our accumulator up to keep track of the last number looked at, whether the last number was at an "even" position, and the sums.

```
# List.fold_left 
    (fun (last, is_even, (s1, s2)) x -> 
       (x, 
        not is_even, 
        if is_even then (s1+x, s2) 
        else (s1, s2+x))) 
    (0, true, (0, 0)) 
    [2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : int option * bool * (int * int) = (6, false, (12, 8))
```

Now, we can run this and pattern-match out the parts of that tuple. If `is_even` is false, we can add the last number to the second sum. We'll just return the sums, discarding the no longer relevant data.

```
# let f lst =
    let (last, is_even, (s1, s2 as sums)) = 
      List.fold_left 
        (fun (last, is_even, (s1, s2)) x -> 
           (x, 
            not is_even, 
            if is_even then (s1+x, s2) 
            else (s1, s2+x))) 
        (0, true, (0, 0)) 
        lst
    in
    if is_even then sums
    else (s1, s2 + last);;
val f : int list -> int * int = <fun>
# f [2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : int * int = (12, 14)
# f [6];;
- : int * int = (6, 6)
# f [];;
- : int * int = (0, 0)
```